# ISA 2006 logs showing lots of dropped packets

Tags: isa-server

We've noticed a drop in internet performance recently and looking through the ISA logs today I can see that servers are dropping up to 6,000 packets a day.

I presume this is not normal - is it? If not, what can I do to fault find the problem?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What servers are you referring to? Internal servers or external servers? What protocol are you seeing with these dropped packets, HTTP, SMTP, etc? It could be perfectly normal depending on your firewall rules. How does ISA handle traffic that doesn't match a rule? Does it drop the connection?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply - I'm referring to the internal network here. The server with the highest dropped packets is a server 2008 R2 terminal server, followed by a Server 2008 R2 DC. The next is actually a network printer though I've just seen.
I've only seen these in the ISA logs though, so I've no other information about what kind of protocols they are. I'll see if I can alter the monitoring to give more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropped packets are *de rigeur* for ISA Server, and 6000 is not a lot for all but the tiniest network (my TMG box chews through that many UPNP packets in an hour, I reckon!)

It's designed to drop packets if it can't work out what to do with them (i.e. if it doesn't match a rule, or if a client goes overboard).

First, check the Reason code if you think the drops are significant. If your dropped packets are dropped with a flood prevention - type reason code, you may need to implement custom IP limits (under Flood Prevention) for the Terminal Server - it'll source a multiple of the number of connections on one box as it has users, so the one-box limit (think it's ~160 TCPs or HTTPs or similar) might need to yield to an insanely-high Custom limit for that IP.

If there's no such warning, or if it's a warning related to an unexpected protocol, troubleshoot that.

If not, you can use the "processing time" column in the log viewer for better visibility on what requests are taking a long time - keep in mind that some requests are by-design amazingly long-lived (facebook chat; OWA; Outlook Anywhere RPC/HTTP) so they'll skew the average.

You can check Event Logs for indications of authentication slowness, as long as your ISA box is up to date (> SP1) - it logs events when DCs or authentication sources are running slowly.

And you can use Perfmon logging (create a log with a 30 second interval, logged to BLG, not one of the slow text formats) to evaluate the rough throughput of the box at any given moment - ensure you capture all ISA-related objects (and all counters - just log the object), then look for slowness, and see if you can correlate with a cause. Of particular interest might be: request speed, requests/sec, backlogged packets, pending DNS resolutions.

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much for that. I hadn't realised that requests which don't match a rule become dropped packets. The dropped packets now make sense at least.